# Classes packages don't include src.main.java, however it is there and eclipse complains about it

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've downloaded an open source library which has the source laid out like this:

```
src.main.java.company.name
```

However the source files always have their package name omitting the `src.main.java` part, for example:

```
package company.name.DataAccessControler
```

and eclipse complains about it. Of course I could rename each file, but there are dozens of files and I'm pretty sure I'm missing something.

The `pom.xml` doesn't have any references to `src.main.java`.

What could be the cause of it, and how to fix it? I believe it might related to eclipse.

Comment: Go into project properties and add src/main/java as a source folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your library... Since this is a Maven project, `/src/main/java` is the default directory layout :

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

You shouldn't touch the build path since this is managed by the Maven Plugin in Eclipse.

Try a right-click - Maven - Update.

Comment: Alright, cool. I discovered what I did wrong: I should've imported it as a maven project (d'uh). Thanks.

Comment: That too :) Glad you found a solution to your problem.